# how to get user details using Oracle Apex LDAP authentication scheme

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using Oracle Apex v5.1 and application is using LDAP authentication. 
I have a separate 'Create new user' form in application which is inserting user details such as NT-IDs, privilege into a user table. 
Whenever user is logging to application, login password is been taken care by LDAP directory.

I want to know that is there any way to get user details such as full name, email address etc from LDAP directory instead of manual insertion into my user table?
What query I can use, so that User name/Email id will automatically inserted into table once user has created in that Oracle Apex form.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to LDAP using PL/SQL APIs, as described by [Tim](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ldap-from-plsql-9i)

You could then construct a [pipelined function](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/pipelined-table-functions) around this to allow you to query using SQL.

For performance, you could create a materialised view on this query.

This technique was also described in a chapter of an APEX book co-authored with John Scott.